# How to println the java.library.path in Groovy

Tags: groovy, grails

I would like to println the current java.library.path I used for the current grails application, how can I do this in groovy?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
println System.properties['java.library.path']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
println System.properties["java.library.path"]
```